# Folder exclusion formatting issue

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, wildcards, make

I'm trying to create make targets for flawfinder and cppcheck that will recursively search the current directory, but ignore directories named "Test".
However, I have run into some issues with formatting.

My user written and script commands look identical when displayed on the terminal

Terminal display of my user input:

```
cppcheck --quiet --force !(Tests)
```

Vs terminal display of makefile output when I run **make .securityCheck**:

```
=================== cppcheck ======================
Tue Aug 29 13:32:00 PDT 2017
===================================================
cppcheck --quiet --force !(Tests)
```

When executed the makefile script creates the error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

while my user input evaluates correctly

**Makefile:**

```
CPPCHECK ?= cppcheck
CPPCHECK_FLAGS += --quiet --force

FLAWFINDER ?= flawfinder
FLAWFINDER_FLAGS += --quiet --dataonly --minlevel 4

SOURCES ?= !(Tests)

.securityCheck:
  @$(ECHO) =================== cppcheck ======================
  @$(DATE)
  @$(TIME)
  @$(ECHO) ===================================================
  $(CPPCHECK) $(CPPCHECK_FLAGS) $(SOURCES)

  @$(ECHO) ================== flawfinder =====================
  @$(DATE)
  @$(TIME)
  @$(ECHO) ===================================================
  $(FLAWFINDER) $(FLAWFINDER_FLAGS) $(SOURCES)
```

Currently using kubuntu 16.04 LTS. uname -a gives the linux version as 4.10.0-33-generic. make --version gives GNU Make 4.1. Also using bash.

Comment: [PSA: Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086/135943)

Comment: @Wildcard thanks, edited formatting for readability

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm using kubuntu 16.04 LTS. uname -a gives the linux version as **4.10.0-33-generic**. make --version gives **GNU Make 4.1**. I am also using **bash**.

Comment: @Aidan please include those version details in the Question itself; comments can be deleted or skipped over. Thank you!

Comment: @JeffSchaller Fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the error that you see may be `cppcheck` running with `Makefile` (or some other non-C or non-C++ source code file in the current directory) as input file.

I suggest that you instead of setting `SOURCES` to `!(Tests)`, set it to the actual source code files of the program that you'd like to run `cppcheck` on.